# Symfony 4 YAML translations not found

Tags: translation, symfony4

I ran `composer require symfony/translation`

I got the file **project_folder/translations/messages.en.yaml**
with this entry:

```
pub_home: home
```

And the twig is : `{{'pub_home'|trans}}`

My **project_folder/config/packages/translations.yaml** is

```
framework:
    default_locale: 'en'
    translator:
        fallbacks: ['en']
        # ...
```

But the translation is missed, displaying the profiler the locale 'en' and domain 'messages' and the 'pub_home' MessageID.

On SF3 the same yaml and twig were working fine. What Am I Missing?

Comment: Shouldn't the config file be in `config/packages/translations.yaml`? The `web` directory is a holdover from sf3.

Comment: Sorry, the web it's the project name, I'm editing it ...